# How can i print all the even positions of an array?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to execute a Bash script with `bash launch_script_even.sh one two three four five six seven eight`. It needs to put `one two three four five six seven eight` in  a array and print only `two four six eight`.(the even positions of the array)

The result in console:

```
Launch_script_even
arguments:8
two four six eight
```

```
echo "name of script is $0"
echo "arguments:$#"
echo "$@"
echo "...
```

Comment: If you want people to help you with (what I assume is) homework, you need to make a serious attempt yourself and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: @tomfenech thanks for looking in to my question , keep in mind that Asking for help can be surprisingly hard . that being said i will use your input toward next questions

Answer (score 0):

A solution to get the requested result

Name script : launch_script_even

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "name of script is $0"
echo "arguments:$#"
args=("$@")
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++ )); do          
    if (( i % 2 == 0 )); then
        echo ${args[$i - 1]}
    fi
done
```

Call : bash launch_script_even one two three four five six seven eight

result:

```
name of script is launch_script_even.sh
arguments:8
two
four
six
eight
```

Comment: It won't work if you pass `two one four three six eight` or like so in the argument..

Comment: @Jahid thanks for you're input this make's me see my mistake in my question i changed that now i needed to print the even positions of the array